# matching characters

Tags: php, regex, arrays, string

I have this string in $output:

```
attack-responses.rules attack-responses_IPS.rules backdoor.rules backdoor_IPS.rules
```

I want to have this in $array:

```
$array[0]=attack-responses.rules
$array[1]=attack-responses_IPS.rules
$array[2]=backdoor.rules
```

I mean when it reaches to .rules(something like *.rules) it must get the substring

I didn't know how to do it with regex or by another solution

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a simple `explode()` should do it

```
$array=explode(' ', $output);
```

Comment: I'm confuesed yes yours is ok but I have this `$output=shell_exec('ls /srv/www/htdocs/didebansnort/core/snort/rules');` and when I get the $output it will not show it anyway I accept yours Thanks

Comment: Then this are line breaks, try `explode("\n", $output)` instead of `explode(' ', $output)`

Comment: My fault, `shell_exec()` returns output as string, so my original answer should work. (to find out the separator you can loop through the string and output `ord()` for each char)

Comment: I didn't know about ideone.com.  Nice.

Comment: @Negin: have a look at http://ideone.com/ANj5t to see how to iterate through a string

Comment: I must do what?? ord is for ascii what do you mean?

Comment: Hehe, my last example gives you the ordinal representation of an ASCII character.  I assume your `$output` string is separated by a space (ordinal character 32). As you said, my answer didn't work for you, we have to find out, what is the correct separator in your string. For that, just try my last example an pass **your** `$output` to the `foreach` loop

Comment: space is 32 You mean I must explode with ascii?

Comment: no, you have to get the ordinal value of each character from `$output=shell_exec('ls /srv/www/htdocs/didebansnort/core/snort/rules');` to see which exactly value we have to use in `explode()` for splitting the string

Comment: I found that seperator is with ascii 10

Comment: Great, this is a `newline` so `$array=explode("\n", $output);print_r($array);` should show you some output

Comment: Yes! Thank you very much You did it sorry for the past! why it showed me none! it was the same!!! sorry for my fault

Answer (score 0):

Call the `preg_split` function on `$output` using a regex containing a space (or `\s+`) if you allow multiple spaces between words.

See http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php

ADDENDUM:

A nice way to try these things out (you probably already know about it) is http://writecodeonline.com/php/.

Type the following in and hit the "Run Code" link:

```
$output = "attack-responses.rules attack-responses_IPS.rules backdoor.rules backdoor_IPS.rules";

$array = preg_split("/ /", $output);

echo "${array[0]}<br />";
echo "${array[1]}<br />";
echo "${array[2]}<br />";
```

This version uses only a simple space for the splitter.

Comment: It outputs me whole in array[0]